# Error about Prisma in Remix's Jokes App tutorial

Tags: reactjs, prisma, remix.run

In Remix's Jokes App tutorial, I got an error in the process of getting a user in session.server.ts.

I think the error is about Prisma, but I don't know how to solve it.

url: https://remix.run/docs/en/v1/tutorials/jokes#authentication

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'findUnique')
    at login (/usr/src/app/remix-jokes/build/index.js:700:30)
    at action2 (/usr/src/app/remix-jokes/build/index.js:751:26)
    at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async Object.callRouteAction (/usr/src/app/remix-jokes/node_modules/@remix-run/server-runtime/data.js:36:14)
    at async renderDocumentRequest (/usr/src/app/remix-jokes/node_modules/@remix-run/server-runtime/server.js:216:24)
    at async requestHandler (/usr/src/app/remix-jokes/node_modules/@remix-run/server-runtime/server.js:55:20)
    at async /usr/src/app/remix-jokes/node_modules/@remix-run/express/server.js:45:22
```

It seems to occur in the `findUnique` call in the following code.

```
export async function login({
  username,
  password
}: LoginForm) {
  const user = await db.user.findUnique({
    where: { username }
  });
  if (!user) return null;

  const isCorrectPassword = await bcrypt.compare(
    password,
    user.passwordHash
  );
  if (!isCorrectPassword) return null;

  return user;
}
```

Comment: Have you run `npx prisma db push` to apply your schema changes to the DB?

Comment: I tried the following command many times, but it was the same.

``$ npx prisma db push $ npx prisma db seed``

Comment: Can you show your schema file?

Answer (score 1):

I restarted the Docker container and that solved the problem.
Thank you.